# Light4J Oauth2 docker-compose error's saying Cannot locate specified Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, light-4j

Followed what was given in the documentation about running light4J oAuth locally. I was able to run maven clean install on the whole repo but when i try running the docker compose up it fails saying DockerFile does not exist. Below is the main repository of the light4J oAuth repo.
https://github.com/networknt/light-oauth2

The documentation steps followed.
https://doc.networknt.com/getting-started/light-oauth2/

Ran "mvn clean install" followed by "docker-compose -f docker-compose-mysql.yml up".
Gives the following error. "ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile".

Following is the docker installation on mac.
[docker-installtion-on-mac-local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZSSV.png)

If anyone knows what might be the problem and direct me to the right direction that would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at your repository. It seems like your *Dockerfile* is located under `code/docker`, `service/docker`, etc. instead of just `code/`, `service/`, etc.

See the [build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) for more information.

> `build` can be specified either as a string containing a path to the build context:
> Example for docker-docs

```yml
version: "3.8"
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: ./dir
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-alternate
      args:
        buildno: 1
```

---

Try this instead (example for one of your containers)

```yml
 oauth2-code:
      build: 
         context: ./code/docker
         dockerfile: Dockerfile # Not mandatory
[...]
```